# Could some please explain Date maxDate = list.stream().map(u -> u.date).max(Date::compareTo).get();

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Could some one please explain this:

```
Date maxDate = list.stream().map(u -> u.date).max(Date::compareTo).get();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The expression `.max(Date::compareTo)` unnecessarily creates a custom comparator which will call the `compareTo` method, as `Date` implements `Comparable`, so `.max(Comparator.naturalOrder())` would do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to understand would be to decompose that into smaller pieces. Imagine a class that holds a `Date object`:

```
static class Holder {
    public Date date;

    public Holder(Date d) {
        super();
    }
}

List<Holder> list= Arrays.asList(new Holder(new Date()));

// creates a Stream<Holder> having the list as the source
Stream<Holder> s1 = list.stream();

// creates a Stream<Date> by taking the previous elements from the Stream
// and mapping those to `Date date`
Stream<Date> s2 = s1.map(u -> u.date);

// consumes the stream by invoking max using the compareTo method
// two Date objects are Comparable by invoking compareTo 
Optional<Date> optionalDate = s2.max(Date::compareTo);

// gets the maxValue from that Optional
// if the initial list is empty, your last get will throw a NoSuchElementException
Date maxDate = optionalDate.get();
```

Comment: Could you please tell one more quetion that:
/*** Stream<Date> s2 = s1.map(u -> u.date); ****/
 what is "u" over here?? Is it the clas name(ex: Holder)??

Comment: `u` is simply the variable name for the `Holder` in this case. you could name it anything you want. You could also declare it like this: `(Holder holder) -> holder.date`; but the type is inferred by the compiler usually.

Answer (score 3):

```
Date maxDate = 
    list.stream() // create a Stream<TheElementTypeOfTheList>
        .map(u -> u.date) // map each element of a Date, thus creating a Stream<Date>
        .max(Date::compareTo) // find the max Date of the Stream
        .get(); // return that max Date (will throw an exception if the
                // list is empty)
```

Comment: Could you please tell one more quetion that: /*** Stream<Date> s2 = s1.map(u -> u.date); ****/ what is "u" over here?? Is it the clas name(ex: Holder)??